# GetProcAddress function usage throughout classes

Tags: c++, getprocaddress

I am using a DLL provided by a fellow programmer that offers certain functions I want to use in my application. The below code works as long as I use the imported functions in the same .cpp file - but not throughout all separate classes:

**main.h**

```
typedef void(*SendChat)(char*);
```

**main.cpp**

```
SendChat _SendChat;

HINSTANCE hMain = 0;
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID)
{
    if(reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _beginthread(WorkerThread,0,NULL);

        hMain = LoadLibraryA("calculate.dll");
        if (hMain)
            _SendChat = (SendChat)GetProcAddress(hMain, "SendChat");
    }
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        //..
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The _SendChat works and does what it should do when I use it within main.cpp but as soon as I use it in the following class it does not work:

**client.h**

```
#include "main.h"
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include "client.h"

void MyClient::Send(char* Message)
{
    _SendChat(Message);
}
```

It makes sense as there's no definition of _SendChat anywhere in the client.cpp except I tried looking on how to solve this but I found nearly nothing - which makes me think I am not looking right.

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Looking at your code i'm assuming you are building a dll. Did you debug at MyClient::Send and checked the _SendChat points to the one in GetProcAddress() return value?

Comment: Are you getting a compile or runtime error? What is the error?

Comment: A compiler error: "_SendChat: identifier not found" in client.cpp.

Comment: What you are doing is illegal, DllMain() is not allowed to use LoadLibrary().  The usual result is deadlock on the loader lock.  You've got a thread, it can call it.  And friends don't let friends use GetProcAddress(), they give them an import library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the compile error you need to declare variable `_SendChat` to be visible in the file where you want to use it. In `main.h` after `typedef void(*SendChat)(char*);` you can write the following:

```
extern SendChat _SendChat;
```

Comment: Really, the moment I read this I wondered why I did not think of it myself. Thanks a lot. Sometimes I shouldn't listen to all the C programmers around me, with their way too complicated view on things. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal path to a working solution would be to declare `_SendChat` as `extren` in your main.h file.  This tells the compiler that this variable name is valid and declared somewhere, and the linker will sort it out at link time:

`extern SendChat _SendChat;`

However, doing this your cluttering up your global namespace and not being a good citizen.  I'd argue that you should really put your DLL functions into their own namespace or class and let everything share it.

**DLLFuncs.h**

```
typedef void(*SendChatFunc)(char*);

namespace DLLFunctions
{
  SendChatFunc SendChat;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "DllFuncs.h"

HINSTANCE hMain = 0;
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID)
{
    if(reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        _beginthread(WorkerThread,0,NULL);

        hMain = LoadLibraryA("calculate.dll");
        if (hMain)
            DLLFunctions::SendChat = (SendChatFunc)GetProcAddress(hMain, "SendChat");
    }
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        //..
    }
    return 1;
}
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include "client.h"
#include "DLLFuncs.h"

void MyClient::Send(char* Message)
{
    DLLFunctions::SendChat(Message);
}
```